# Dates Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column with many thousands of rows. The column is meant to be date and is of the format dd/mm/yyyy

But, when I try to do formulas based on the dates, something is clearly amiss.

For example, if you try to apply autofilter on the dates, some of them are grouped as a year with the expandable boxes while others appear as their own items.

For each record I tried a formula to parse it apart.`=DATE(RIGHT(A2,4),MID(A2,4,2),LEFT(A2,2))`

That did not help.

I also selected the column and switched it from general to date format

I really don't know how to ask the question any clearer. I can tell you that with a date of the format 1/11/2013 when I run `=year(right(A1,4))` I get `1903` instead of `2013`. When I run `=date(right(A1,4),mid(A1,3,2),left(A1,2))` the formula returns `2/10/3192`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple why your formulas doesn't work corectly. When yor're using somehting like this: `RIGHT(A2,4)`, your value from `A2` translates to 41579 for 1/11/2013 (Excel stores all dates as integers and all times as decimal fractions. You can read more [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214094/en-us)). Next formula should work well:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(TEXT(A2,"dd/mm/yyyy"),4),MID(TEXT(A2,"dd/mm/yyyy"),4,2),LEFT(TEXT(A2,"dd/mm/yyyy"),2))
```

Btw, if you'd like to get correct format for dates, you can add formula in some empty column (but before set date format for this column):

```
=A2*1
```

and drag it down. Then copy values from this temp column and paste them using "Paste special->Values" in colunm `A` (where should be date format as well)

[image]

Or you can use this simple macro:

```
Sub test()
    With Range("A2:A100")
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you clarify your sentence: "Btw, if you'd like to get correct format for dates, you can add formula in some empty column (but before set date format for this column):
" Does this mean that if I do this I do not need to enter the formula you provided?

Comment: @DougFirr, it's much easier to use my macro. Or you can do following: let your date be in `A2:A100`. Let your column `Z` is empty. Select column `Z` and apply dates format for it. Than write in `Z2` formula `=A2*1` and drag it down until `Z100`. Than select column `A` and apply dates format as well. Copy values from `Z2:Z100` and make paste special->paste values in `A2:A100`. Thats all)

Comment: if you have additional questions, please ask:)

Comment: and yes, there is no need to use this awful formula: `=DATE(RIGHT(TEXT(A2,"dd/mm/yyyy"),4),MID(TEXT(A2,"dd/mm/yyyy"),4,2),LEFT(TEXT(A2,"dd/mm/yyyy"),2))`

Comment: Thanks again @simoco. So I tried what you said in your last comment. In column Z I format as date, then write =G2*1 which produces #value.
In G2 there is 26/10/13 and it's format is general (I had not yet reached the step where I change it to date format). Am I missing something?

Comment: Does your `G2` has some spaces or `"` ? it shouldn't return #value

Comment: lets try `=TRIM(G2)*1`. Is it return `#VALUE` too?

Comment: Same reult I'm afraid :-(

Comment: ok, try to use `=DATE(RIGHT(TEXT(G2,"dd/mm/yyyy"),2),MID(TEXT(G2,"dd/mm/yyyy"),4,2),LEFT(TEXT(G2,"dd/mm/yyyy"),2))`

Comment: Thank you very much it works now! If I interpret it right, we have converted each component of the =date formula to text, then custom formatted each one? How would you word it? Thanks again

Comment: yes, you're right! we can't apply `RIGHT(G2,2)` directly, because dates in excel are `double` values and we have to convert it to the text.